# How to ignore a specific sub-string from Splunk query

Tags: regex, splunk

Need some help to generate appropriate Spunk query. I am searching for this but could not come up with a solution.

Currently, I want to ignore all error alerts that are generated for logs with only ev31=*error*; term. If we use NOT ev31=*error*; in search query, it also removes results with valid error terms. So the current query will fail in case log contains both error and ev31=*error*; terms resulting in incorrect results.

Can anyone suggest a example query, where we can ignore ev31=*error*; term altogether but keep logs with error term.

Answer (score 16):

Try including the string you want to ignore in quotes, so your search might look something like `index=myIndex NOT "ev31=error"`

Comment: Yep. You need the double quotes around the String you need to exclude.

Comment: yes, and you can select the text 'ev31=233o3' with your mouse and select the pupup list, exclude..